# Remove deployment table for a type

Tags: performance, migration, sap-commerce-cloud

In the current project(which is live), we have a type `CSCategory` with the deployment table. CSCategory extends `Category` also there are many references to `CSCategory` from other types. It could be 1-1, 1-N or N-N.

Obvious, this leads to performance issue and we are facing it. So we want to remove the deployment table for `CSCategory` type.

I know [this steps](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/71075/how-to-remove-deployment-tag-for-a-subtype.html)

**Any better approach? or the only way is to export CSCategory data along with dependent types data and reimport it?**

Answer (score 0):

I have done what you have suggested in our project.

Since the records are already in Table_X, you would have to export the items of Type_X, remove the items of Type_X (which will remove them from Table_X), and reimport them as Type_Y. If there are other types dependent on them, you would have to consider them in the data migration as well.

After that, it should be safe to remove the deployment tag, and to drop the database table. If necessary, you have have to remove the orphaned types via HAC as well.

I can't think of another or better way of doing it.

Comment: What I am trying is, `exported CSCategory data >removed deployment tag from code > update the system > then will try to reImport data` let's me see what happen. I hope all  'CSCategor` atrributes will generates in `Category`

Comment: @HybrisHelp I have a feeling it's not going to work, because the PKs in CSCategory table will be different from the PKs in Category table. Take note that when you specify a deployment table, you also specify a type code, and the type code is part of the PK. So, I think you're going to have to migrate everything, including records/references that depend on them.

Comment: Yes I know the Pk would be different. But trying something to avoid full migration. let's see

Comment: @HybrisHelp Let me know how it goes. I'm curious. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, is the only long way to go :) I had exported all data including dependencies and reImported it after data model changes.